# How to ask for integer input from the user until he enters blank line in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, validation, vector, getline

So I need to store user inputs in a vector until he entersa blank line (or an invalid input). I've tried to convert the input to string, then compare it to a blank line, but it didn't work. Here's the code:

```
int input;
vector<int> v;
do
{
    cout << "Write a number!" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    v.push_back(input);
} while (to_string(input) != "");
```

Is there any way to do that?

**UPDATE**

Thank you guys so much for your help! The second answer solved all of my problems and the first one helped me to understand the logical background of it.

Comment: Use `std::getline` to get a line, check if it is an empty string.  If it is not an empty string, use `std::stringstream ss(input);` to `ss >> input;`.

Comment: [Read full lines into a string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), strip leading and trailing white-space, and see if the line is empty. If it is then you have an empty line, else attempt to convert the string to a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep looping until user enters a blank line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041615/keep-looping-until-user-enters-a-blank-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use standard function `std::getline`. Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number (Enter - exit): ";
        std::string line;

        if ( not std::getline( std::cin, line ) or line.empty() ) break;

        try
        {
            int value = std::stoi( line );
            v.push_back( value );
        }
        catch ( ... )
        {
            std::cout << "Not an integer number\n";
        }           
    }

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a number (Enter - exit): 1
Enter a number (Enter - exit): 2
Enter a number (Enter - exit): 3
Enter a number (Enter - exit): A
Not an integer number
Enter a number (Enter - exit): 4
Enter a number (Enter - exit): 5
Enter a number (Enter - exit): 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse your logic: instead of *reading integers until something*, you can *read strings, check if they are empty and then convert them to integers*.

```
std::string input;
std::vector<int> v;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
while(!input.empty())
{
    int number = std::stoi(input);
    v.push_back(number);
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
}
```

Notice that `std::cin` will not work, because it ignores whitespace (including newline character). Also, mixing `std:: cin >>` with `std::getline` is [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: This is troublesome because all input with the stream extract operator `>>` by default skips white-space. And the newline is a white-space character. So `std::cin >> input` will only return if some non-space input is entered.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hmm, that's right. I'll change it to getline